# Run PHP script in background using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have some PHP that takes some time that runs in the background. I just want my code to say "Command executed. Invites pending." - And that will be all that the user will see from their end. Everything else in my .php script will be done in the background.

I was thinking about somehow executing it with jQuery and have it stop loading the script mid-execute of the post. And then use ignore_user_abort()

Here is the jQuery code I plan on using:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { ' MyPostData'},
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'myPHP.php',
    success: function (d) { /* commands */ }
});
```

The only thing I'm missing is having it stop the call after it's originally called upon, and then I need for it to append to a div saying "Invites Pending."

Comment: A suggestion for this is to look into actually making your long running processes run in the background. You could use something like beanstalkd (check pheanstalk for a php implementation of it), but you would need the ability to install beanstalkd on your server. A cron based solution might also work

Comment: Could you not just add async:true and update the wording in the div then you shouldn't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Almost identical to jquery's site example:

```
alert( "initializing..." ); 

var jqxhr = $.post( "myPHP.php", function(data) {
  alert( "working..." );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "finished!" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error!!" );
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following line in your myPHP.php file.

```
  echo "Command executed. Invites pending.";
```

JavaScript code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 data:$(this).serialize(),
 dataType: 'html',
 url: 'myPHP.php',
 success: function (d) {//begin success

    //add the pending message to a div on the page
    $("#result").html(d);

 }//end success
});
```

HTML needed on your page:

```
         <!-- results from the ajax function will be displayed here -->
         <div id = "result"></div>
```

Comment: Okay. Will that not keep the user waiting on the page to finish loading while it waits on the php?

Comment: I believe I may have misunderstood your question.  Do you want to block the user from doing anything until the php script is finished running?